# Running Flex in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex

I have a Java project and Flex together in Eclipse. The Java is the server and Flex is the client.

I once (this morning) could just right click on my main.mxml -> RunAs->FlexApplication and that would launch the client.

I messed up the project somehow ( deleted the main.mxml, then returned ti etc...) and can not run it now.

What I am trying to do is right click->RunConfigurations... and trying to configure it. But can't!

My other group member has a file name in "Application File:" dialog. I don't have and ant add.

Anyway any ideas how can I configure the main.mxml to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click your new application file and select "set as default application".  That should recompile the project and make it available to you in the "run configuration" Dialog.